# Mount directory in/from android device

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there a way to mount a directory from the host machine (windows) on an android device/emulator, or vice-versa, assuming it is plugged in via usb?

Comment: do you have root permission? Why is it tagged android-nkd?

Comment: I might not have root permission. I tagged it under android-ndk because I would like to know if there's a way to do this regardless of it being with java or c++

Comment: Many App-based solutions get around the permission requirement for mounting by not actually doing a mount, but rather doing their own operations between local files and remote network resources.  That tends to mean that only the App (or perhaps things which use it as a content provider) can access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

`mount` requres root permissions. You have /sdcard "mounted" on Windows host, though. You only must choose how the device works with its USB connection. You cannot do this programmatically. That is, unless your program has root permissions.

Comment: You are correct about the permission issue, however I believe the goal is in the opposite direction from USB Mass Storage or MTP, which mount a device directory to the PC.